# Is there a more efficient way of reading a formatted file in C than I have done?

Tags: c, file-io, whitespace, scanf

I need to read in a formatted file that looks something like this.

Code: HARK

Name: Oscar

MRTE: Train

etc

At the moment my code looks like this.

```
FILE *file;
char unneeded[10];
char whitespace[2];
char actual[10];
file = fopen("scannertest.txt","r");
fscanf(file,"%s",unneeded); // this is the identifier and the colon (code:)
fscanf(file,"%[ ]",whitespace); // this takes in the white space after the colon.
fscanf(file,"%s",actual); // this is the value I actually need.
/**
* Do stuff with the actual variable
**/
fclose(file);
```

This way works for me but I don't think writing three fscanf()'s for each line in the text file is the best way to do it, especially as I will be doing it in a loop later.

I tried doing it like this:

```
fscanf(file, "%s %[ ] %s",unneeded,whitespace,real);
```

However this gave me weird symbols when I tried printing the output.

Answer (score 4):

The `%s` scanf specifier already ignores spaces. If you do

```
scanf("%s%s", unneeded, actual)
```

and the input is "Code: HARK", `unneeded` will have "Code:" and `actual` will have "HARK".

Warning: `scanf` is a troublesome function (it's "difficult" to use safely). If you want more safety, specify the maximum number of characters (remember the zero terminator) you are willing to accept into each string

```
scanf("%9s%9s", unneeded, actual); /* arrays defined with 10 elements */
```

The best is to use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.

*Edit after reading a comment to another answer*

**And remember to *always* check the return value of `scanf`.**

```
chk = scanf("%9s%9s", unneeded, actual);
if (chk != 2) /* error reading data */;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, the file functions use buffered I/O. This means that fscanf won't be hitting the disk with each call so the performance loss of using 3 calls instead of 1 should be negligible.

**However**, the best thing to do is get your program working and then if it's too slow **measure** where the performance bottlenecks are and fix those first. It's not worth it trying to guess what sections of code will cause performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because

```
fscanf(file,"%s",unneeded);
fscanf(file,"%[ ]",whitespace);
fscanf(file,"%s",actual);
```

does not do the same thing as

```
fscanf(file,"%s %[ ] %s", unneeded, whitespace, actual);
```

it is functionally equivalent

```
fscanf(file,"%s%[ ]%s", unneeded, whitespace, actual); // No spaces in fmt string
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ways to speed up your code, you could read in your entire file, or a buffer of the file.  Reading an entire block at a time would be faster than reading in data as you need it.

You can then use `sscanf` on the buffer you read.

Comment: i tried using sscanf on a fgets() I had it like this.

fgets(line,20,file);
sscanf(line,"%s %[ ] %s,unneeded,whitespace,actual);

But this still gave me the same problem, weird symbols going into the variables.

Comment: Sounds more like you're overflowing a buffer if you're seeing strange symbols. Be very sure to check the return value of sscanf , so you know it actually read something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sick person who misses coding in C every now and then. I wrote out something that appears to work:

Contents of test.txt

```
Code: HARK
Name: Oscar
MRTE: Train
```

Contents of text.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256

int main(void)
{
  FILE *file;
  char str_buf[MAX_LEN + 1]; // One extra byte needed
                             // for the null character
  char unneeded[MAX_LEN+1];
  char actual[MAX_LEN+1];


  file = fopen("test.txt","r");

  while(fgets(str_buf, MAX_LEN + 1, file) != NULL)
  {
    sscanf(str_buf, "%s%s", unneeded, actual);
    printf("unneeded: %s\n", unneeded);
    printf("actual: %s\n", actual);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output of compiled code:

```
unneeded: Code:
actual: HARK
unneeded: Name:
actual: Oscar
unneeded: MRTE:
actual: Train
```